# Multiple Realm File opened on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, realm

I've an application when users can save their ECG. I want to split Realm usage by user. I'm developing a `user.realm` (referenced as `_realmUsers`) to save all the users that login on application, and a `userID.realm`  (referenced as `_realm` and They will be once per user that login on application) where user saves his data. How to achieve that? Because if I write things like

Initialization of both Realms

```
+ (void)initializeRealmForUsers
{
    // Open the encrypted Realm file
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    config.fileURL = [[[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                       URLByAppendingPathComponent:USER_REALM]
                      URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"];

    NSError *err;
    RLMRealm *realmUser = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:&err];
    if(err == nil && realmUser != nil)
        [sharedInstance setRealmUsers:realmUser];
}

+ (void)initializeDataRealmWithUserID:(NSString*)userUUID
{
    // Open the encrypted Realm file
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    config.fileURL = [[[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                       URLByAppendingPathComponent:userUUID]
                      URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"];

    NSError *err;
    RLMRealm *realmUser = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:&err];
    if(err == nil && realmUser != nil)
        [sharedInstance setRealmUsers:realmUser];

    [[RealmManager sharedInstance] deleteIncompleteExam];

}
```

Creation of User:

```
- (User *)createUserWithData:(NSDictionary *)data
{
    [_realmUsers beginWriteTransaction];

    User *newUser = [User new];
    [newUser setEmail:[data objectForKey:USER_EMAIL]];
    [newUser setPassword:[CryptoUtils MD5String:[data 
    objectForKey:USER_PASSWORD]]];
    [newUser setLogged:@NO];

    [_realmUsers addOrUpdateObject:newUser];
    [_realmUsers commitWriteTransaction];

    return newUser;
}
```

Creation of Patient, a record type of the second realm (the specific-user one):

```
- (Patient *)createPatientWithData:(NSDictionary *)data forUser:(BOOL)forUser
{
    Patient *newPatient;
    if([[RealmManager sharedInstance] getSelfPatient] == nil)
        newPatient = [Patient new];
    else
        newPatient = [[RealmManager sharedInstance] getSelfPatient];

    [_realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [newPatient setFirstName:[data objectForKey:PATIENT_FIRSTNAME]];
    [newPatient setLastName:[data objectForKey:PATIENT_LASTNAME]];
    [newPatient setSelfPatient:forUser];
    [_realm addOrUpdateObject:newPatient];
    [_realm commitWriteTransaction];

    return newPatient;
}
```

and Login:

```
- (User *)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password andData:(NSDictionary *)userData
{
    User *user = [self userWithUsername:email];
    if(user == nil){
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [mutableData addEntriesFromDictionary:userData];
        [mutableData setObject:password forKey:USER_PASSWORD];
        user = [self createUserWithData:mutableData];
    } else{
        [_realmUsers beginWriteTransaction];
        [user setPassword:[CryptoUtils MD5String:password]];
        [_realmUsers commitWriteTransaction];
    }

    [_realmUsers beginWriteTransaction];
    [user setLogged:@YES];
    [_realmUsers commitWriteTransaction];

    [RealmManager initializeDataRealmWithUserID:[user uuid]];
    [self createPatientWithData:@{PATIENT_FIRSTNAME : [userData objectForKey:PATIENT_FIRSTNAME], PATIENT_LASTNAME : [userData objectForKey:PATIENT_LASTNAME]} forUser:YES];

    return user;
}
```

After Login, my Calls Like `[User allObjects]` (user must be on user.realm) `[Patient allObject]`(patients must be on userID.realm) gives me empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access datas from different realm by

```
[User allObjectsInRealm: user.realm]

[User objectsInRealm:user.realm where:@""];
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution.

Comment: Happy coding :)